# How to pause Garbage Collection in .NET?

Tags: .net, memory-management, garbage-collection, performance

I'm running some performance tests on some .NET code that processes lots of data.  I want some tests that ensure the garbage collector isn't influencing my results.  How do I temporarily pause the garbage collector?

Comment: I don't see the point.  In the normal execution of your program the garbage collector will be doing its thing.  So, any data you gather when it is not doing its job is useless as it does not reflect the actual performance of your application. Test what you ship.

Comment: @Ed Swangren, well said, I was going to make the same point.

Comment: @Ed Swangren Don't you think being able to compare the results would be helpful in identifying problem areas?

Comment: I don't see the point in testing a scenario that will never be a valid use case.

Comment: Well, I guess to me it makes a difference because I'm testing one part of the a much bigger whole.  The garbage collector works at the "whole level."  So it doesn't seem fair to penalize the measurement of this part's performance because a system at the "whole level" happened to kick in.  Does that make sense?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is not a way to do this through the BCL APIs.

Turning it off for the profiling of a particular algorithm is also not a great idea because it will yield false results.  The garbage collector will run during the execution of your program.  Profiling without the GC could hide real problems with your algorithm if it causes lots of garbage collections in the real world.

Comment: So, I totally didn't appreciate how often the GC runs!  Now that I understand how often the GC collects I understand why my question is mute.  Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

I know I'm a little late to answer this, but according to MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.gcsettings.latencymode.aspx where is a property called `GCSettings.LatencyMode` that can be set to `LowLatency`.  This value will prevent Gen2 GCs unless a low memory condition exists or an explicit call is made to initiate a GC.

Answer (score 2):

The real world will include garbage collection. Since this is a random arrival process (poisson), it might be worthwhile doing it in the monte carlo fashion and doing a few 1000 profiling runs and averaging the results.

Comment: The problem is that the garbage collection's behavior in the test environment and in production aren't necessarily the same.  I'm also comparing the results to non-managed approaches to the problem and think the data would be valuable for comparison.

Comment: Will it be a fair comparison if you ran in unmanaged mode - i.e. different language altogether ?

Comment: I not positive what you are getting at, but I will say this:  If one of the non-managed approaches is in a different language is it fair to penalize the managed approach because during the test it was unlucky enough to have the garbage collection routine run?  No, I don't think so, because I'm interested in the comparison of the parts and the garbage collector is a system for the whole.  The non-managed approach has to worry about memory too, but is able to better optimis (in theroy) in speed senitive areas.

Comment: Since unmanaged mode gives you more predictable behaviour and control that seems to bet the way to go. You can make forced calls to the garbage collector at certain points in managed mode and see how long it takes. There are also GC performance counters that can be used http://blogs.msdn.com/maoni/archive/2004/06/03/148029.aspx.

Comment: So, that gives me an idea.  I can run the test monte carlo fashion like you suggest but throw out the runs that had a collection occur by checking the GC.CollectionCount before and after.  That's seems like a good compromise.

Comment: My idea is useless.  The GC runs so often that a test run is never "good."